# Linear programming maximization code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, equation-solving, linear-equation, maximization

How to solve the  linear programming maximization problem that contains both `<=` and `>=` equations?

For example here's a case:

Maximize:

```
z = c1x1 + c2x2 + c3x3
```

Subject to:

```
a1x1 + a2x2 + a3x3 <= b1
a4x1 + a5x2 + a6x3 <= b2
x1 >= d1
x2 >= d2
x3 >= d3
```

Where `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3` are the constants in the given equations.

What will be the proper Matlab code to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how :

```
    z = -[c1 ; c2 ; c3];

    A = [ a1 a2 a3 ; 
          a4 a5 a6]; 

    b=[b1;
       b2];

    Aeq= [ ]; beq= [ ];

    LB = [d1 ; d2 ; d3]; 

    UB = [1 ; 1 ; 1]* inf; % Any relax number

    x = linprog(z, A, b, Aeq, beq, LB, UB)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sardar_Usama, How can I get the value of z using matlab?

Comment: By putting the values of constants `c1` , `c2` and `c3`

Comment: Do I have to calculate it manually or is there any built-in function to do that?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: It would be a great help if you please add the code that calculates the value of z in your answer.

Comment: if you're asking for the value of this: `z = c1x1 + c2x2 + c3x3` , it doesn't mean anything since `x1`,`x2` and`x3` are decision variables. You can find the value of `z` by putting the different values of these variables and constants `c1`,`c2` and `c3`. And if you want to find the maximum value of `z`, it is already given in the code.

Comment: Okay, if the results obtained for x1 = m, x2 = n and x3 = p; then is it possible to do sensitivity analysis or post optimization analysis on this problem using MATLAB?